# How to pick elements of specific index in python?

Tags: python

Say,

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
```

What I'm trying to get is the specific elements of `A`, e.g. only first and third element.

So the output should look like this:

```
[1, 3]
```

How do I do this?

`print(A(0,2))` is not the right command I know, so looking for the right command.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [slice notation](https://tutorials.technology/tutorials/58-Python-slice-notation-explained.html).

```
print(A[::2]) # this will print each second element of the list.
```

Answer (score 3):

With a small comprehension you can do:

#### Code:

```
[A[i] for i in (0, 2)]
```

#### Test Code:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print([A[i] for i in (0, 2)])
```

#### Results:

```
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will work for any indexes you put into the smaller list below.

```
[e for c,e in enumerate(A) if c in [0,2]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got my solution :-)